# Is there a way to download and install a private conan package locally?

Tags: c++, build, devops, libraries, conan

I want to use conan to download and build some libraries in a **specific folder**.

The idea is that everything included in the `export_sources` field must be downloaded in a **given folder** from which I run the `conan install` command, and not in ~/.conan/data.

Once that is done, I want to move the downloaded files into separate directories (namely include, src, ...) starting from the given folder and then build the library.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it's not possible. The first question is, why do you need it? The most close scenario is when conanfile and project are under the same repository: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_repo.html

Comment: Thanks @uilianries, I need it because I am implementing a microservice on a docker image that requires different libraries. As the libraries are currently under testing, I need to update the code repeadtly. Having them in a given directory would be super useful to interact with them directly from Gitlab pipelines (to automatize both the install and upload process) and the dockerfile itself.

Comment: If you have to change the code repeatedly, you could use Dev flow: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html. Also, you can run docker directly to avoid multiple uploads, for instance: docker run --rm -ti -v ${PWD}:/home/conan/project conanio/gcc9